# Docker Heroku upload fails when it comes to adding the jar file?

Tags: docker, heroku, intellij-idea

When I deploy on Heroku side after pushing my build to GitHub It always returns this error →

**Step 5/6 : ADD ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
ADD failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder947308159/target/google-api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar: no such file or directory**

[image: Dockerfile]

This is the terminal commands Ive tried ->

**docker build -f Dockerfile -t google-api .**

**docker build -t google-api .**

Directory structure in intellij:

[image: test_o]

heroku.yml file

[image]

Comment: Did you build the jar file first (ie `mvn package`)? Is the filename of the jar correct and matching the one in Dockerfile?

Comment: @BeppeC Yes, I have done clean then install via Maven, and the Jar file name matches the one in the Dockerfile

Answer (score 0):

Your local build would push the jar to the local M2 repository. This jar can't be identified during your Heroku docker build phase. The reason is Heroku try to find this jar from your application git repository, where the repository doesn't have this springboot built jar.

Try following the tutorial.

https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2019/08/spring-boot-heroku-docker-jdk11/